# Java - How to make zoom button in barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer library?

Tags: java, pdf

I am using Android PDF Viewer library  from [here](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) to get a PDF file into my android app .. it works fine but i want to add zoom buttons

I know there are 3 different zoom options - min / mid / max - but I don't know how to call it and use in button

I tried this with no result,

```
public static final float DEFAULT_MAX_SCALE = 3.0f;
    public static final float DEFAULT_MID_SCALE = 1.75f;
    public static final float DEFAULT_MIN_SCALE = 1.0f;

    private float minZoom = DEFAULT_MIN_SCALE;
    private float midZoom = DEFAULT_MID_SCALE;
    private float maxZoom = DEFAULT_MAX_SCALE;

public float getMaxZoom() {
        return maxZoom;
    }
```

Regards.